# Trouble after Ubuntu 12.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, kernel, kubuntu, kdm

Over night I tried to upgrade to (k)ubuntu 12.10. Unfortunately kdm (neither lightdm) doesn't show up after boot. I found several posts describing errors due to the migration from kdm to lightdm. Some sugest reinstallation of kdm. Therefore I logged into a shell and tried to install it using `apt-get`. However it turned out that network is not available. `ifconfig` showes that only the loopback device `lo` is available. What can I do to get lan or wlan network working on the commandline? I relized that grub still runs the old tuxonice kernel which I installed from ppa. Is it possible that the installation didn't finish and left me in an inkonsistent state in which the kernel version does not match the modules? How can I proceed the installation from the downloaded packages?

Comment: Try choosing another kernel in Grub from the second option in the menu.

Comment: There are two older (tuxonice) 3.2 kernels. Unfortunately with neiter of them I get a working network.

Comment: I am trying to find out where apt-get stores the downloaded packages. If it downloaded the 3.5. kernel I could install it using dpkg. Any ideas?

Comment: Thats obviously `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. I find that apt-get didn't download any linux-image. Isn't this strange?

Comment: Do you have a 12.10 liveUSB or liveDVD? Try seeing if this works properly. If it does, you may consider downloading manually the kernel deb's, installing it and then remove the tuxonice ones.

Comment: I downloaded the 3.5. kernel saved it on USB storage and installed it manually. However network is still not working with the new kernel. With dmesg I get a lot of messages saying `network-manager main process killed by ABRT signal` and `network-manager respawning too fast, stopped`

Comment: So the liveUSB works well?

Comment: Eventually I managed to get network working and to complete the upgrade. Now the new lightdm fails to log me into kde. I wish I could reinstall kdm which simply worked. But unfortunately the dependencies are such that it is impossible install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade entailed several different problems which I finally managed to fix:

The upgrade was incomplete. Important packages including the new kernel where not even downloaded. This left the system in an inconsistent state. It was possible to boot the system with one of the old kernels. On a different system I downloaded the kernel packages

```
linux-generic
linux-image-generic
```

from `http://packages.ubuntu.com/` and saved them on USB storage.

I mounted the storage from the command line

```
sudo mount -t ext3 /dev/sdb1/ mountpoint
```

and installed them using

```
dpkg --force-all -i mountpoint/linux-*
```

I booted the new kernel and got the network working which appeared in

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

as `DISABLED`. I got it working with

```
sudo modprobe -v r8169
```

which loads the kernel module for my network card. However only upon

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

eth0 appeared in the `ifconfig` list and in `sudo lshw -C network`. As I could connect to the internet now I fixed the upgrade with

```
sudo apt-get -f upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I had to install several blocked packages with `sudo apt-get install [packagename]`. And individual ones (in particular one calligra package) with `dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/[package]` as they had conflicts (common files with different package).

Finally I could boot the complete system but the login manager lightdm still didn't work. Lightdm shows (this is a known bug) a message "low graphics mode". I had to install the package `lightdm-kde-greeter` and to set `greeter-session=lightdm-kde-greeter` in the `lightdm.conf` file.

Finally I had to reinstall sound and graphics related packages to get it those again.